# How to update ComboBox list when new data added to an excel column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update a combobox list on userform1 when I add data into an excel column from userform2.

I've tried several things like .show and .repaint but nothing updates the combobox list. If I close and reopen the userform1 the data will show up.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    UserForm1.Repaint
End Sub
```

Okay, I have a userform1 with a combobox lists, If what you want is not on the list you click an edit button to open userform2. This userform2 inserts data into an excel column. then userform1 reads the data in that column and needs to show that list update in the combobox list.

I'd like to have it update the userform1 list on closing userform2.

[image: UserForm1 and 2]

Comment: Please read the article I linked to in your previous question. Your using of forms' default instances is going to make things impossible to work out. Every time a form is closed with the "X" button, that form instance is destroyed - you need your `QueryClose` handler to set the `Cancel` parameter to `True`, and explicitly `Hide` the form to prevent the object instance from being destroyed. Now, which of these two forms is `UserForm1`, and which is `UserForm2`?

Comment: Is this `QueryClose` handler in the `UserForm1` code-behind? Avoid referring to any form's default instance *from within that form's code-behind*.

Comment: I did read it over, unfortunately most of that is above my current skillset. Userform1 is the large form on the right. and userform2 is the smaller one. I have that QueryClose in form2

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    cancelled = True
    Hide
    
End Sub

Comment: Ok I think I got it!
``Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
     End If
     With New UserForm1
    .Repaint
    
End With
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    cancelled = True
    Hide
End SubPrivate Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
     End If

Comment: Not sure I really understand it, but now I have something else to research. Thank you Mathieu